# Setting up a 301 redirect from different domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I currently have the following setup:

- www.domainx.com - The main website
- www.domainx.de (foreign domain) - This domain redirects to www.domainx.com/de

I need www.domainx.com/product1 redirecting to www.domainx.com/product.php?id=123 - This i've done via .htaccess

The tricky part is trying to get www.domainx.de/product1 to redirect to www.domainx.com/de/product.php?id=123

Any ideas?

Comment: `This i've done via .htaccess` Show us your current .htaccess

Comment: Current .htaccess file is as follows:

DirectoryIndex index.php

Redirect 301 /productx http://www.domainx.com/products/detail.php?id=96

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainx.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainx.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rules like this in you root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^productx/?$ /products/detail.php?id=96 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainx\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product1/?$ http://www.domainx.com/de/product.php?id=123 [L,NC,R=302]
```